# android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an android project using eclipse IDE,its created successfully but the problem is in error log.After creating of a project with name as android_test,the error shown failed to load properties file for project 'android_test'.

Can any one let me know how to over come this problem.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you trying to create new project or import existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start again and be sure to

- have write / read permissions in the folder of your project
- avoid special characters when naming things (project/classes/files/etc)